# Identify patterns in a text variable using regex and create a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame containing court rulings from the Swiss federal court. Each ruling has a file number (e.g. "146 IV 23" or) given in the column `from` and a string variable containing the text of the ruling (variable `text`). In each court ruling there are references to other court rulings using the file number.

Now, I would like to analyze the network of all court rulings and plot a social network map. In order to do that I need a data frame containing information about which rulings contain references to other rulings.

For example case "19 IV 291" contains a reference to the cases "61 IV 281" and "67 IV 291". There can be no reference at all or many references.

```r
df <- data.frame(from = c("19 IV 291",
                          "19 IV 10",
                          "23 IV 1",
                          "10 IV 12",
                          "10 IV 13"),
                 text = c("some long text containing patterns such as 61 IV 281 or 67 IV 291",
                          "random text 61 IV 281 and moral ahserlek gwhjsk bahsek 69 IV 90",
                          "ahkse hauselire 64 IV 13 hasjer gazsekr vgwkjehj 74 IV 14",
                          "ahejbhajl uztfvbn ghsjke 67 IV 291 halser kjgkhweka 69 IV 90",
                          "there's no reference here"))


df
```

How can a make a table containing the file number and the file numbers of the referenced files?

To identify the file numbers I was using  `[0-9]{1,3} (I|II|III|IV) [0-9]{1,3}`.

The output should be like:

```
from        to
19 IV 291   61 IV 281
19 IV 291   67 IV 291
19 IV 10    61 IV 281
19 IV 10    69 IV 90
23 IV 1     64 IV 13
23 IV 1     74 IV 14
10 IV 12    67 IV 291
10 IV 12    69 IV 90
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all()` from the `stringr` package, which returns a list of all matches. Then `unnest` the list column.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(to = str_extract_all(text, "[0-9]{1,3} (I|II|III|IV) [0-9]{1,3}"), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  unnest(to)

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  from      to       
  <chr>     <chr>    
1 19 IV 291 61 IV 281
2 19 IV 291 67 IV 291
3 19 IV 10  61 IV 281
4 19 IV 10  69 IV 90 
5 23 IV 1   64 IV 13 
6 23 IV 1   74 IV 14 
7 10 IV 12  67 IV 291
8 10 IV 12  69 IV 90
```